# numpy: wrong result when casting large float32 to int32

Tags: numpy, casting, floating-point, int32

I have a numpy array of type np.float32 (actually no fraction part), and I expect it to be casted to only the integer part (2143289300), but the result below is different(2143289344), do you know why? i guess it relates to overflow, but what's the correct way to covert float32 to int32 or int64 in numpy? i tried np.trunc, but the result is still float32.

```
t = np.array([2143289300.0],dtype=np.float32)
print(int(t))
print(t.astype(np.int32))
print(t.astype(np.int64))
t2 = np.trunc(t)
print(t2)
print(t2.dtype)

2143289344
[2143289344]
[2143289344]
[2.1432893e+09]
float32
```

Comment: Conversion to int is irrelevant here. The value `2143289300` is not exactly representable as an `np.float32`. The closest value that _is_ exactly representable is `2143289344`, so that's the value that NumPy is storing. That is, the moment you store your value in an `np.float32` array, you're already storing an approximation to the original value. The conversion to `np.int32` or `np.int64` is exact in this case: it's not introducing any additional error.